# Continuous device and connection issues with routed Tokbox session

Tags: webrtc, opentok, tokbox

We’ve been using the [Tokbox](https://tokbox.com/) platform for several months now with a [Javascript web-client](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/) as well as an [Android phone client](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/), where sessions and connections are managed by a [Python server](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Python-SDK). While integration and bring-up went well on both ends (client and server), we continue to encounter problems with the in-session audio and video experience.

Sessions are always [routed](https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/202997234-What-is-the-difference-between-a-Routed-vs-Relayed-Session-) and always between two participants only, with much use of a [collaborative editor](https://github.com/aullman/opentok-editor).

*The in-session experience is like a [coin toss](https://www.random.org/coins/): we never know how it’s going to go, and that’s becoming a business threat.*

**Web-Client: A/V Resources**

The most common problem is the acquisition of audio and/or video: at the beginning of a session, one or the other participants may have problems hearing or seeing the other. Allocating a new connection to establish new streams does not fix that, nor does restarting the browser.

*Question:* What’s the recommended way to detect possible resource locks (e.g. does another application hog the camera/microphone)?

**Web-Client: Network**

Bandwidth and packet loss are a challenge, for example this [inspector](https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/inspector/) graph:

[image]

Audio and video of both participants is all over the place, and while we can not control the network connections the web-client should be able to reliably give useful information.

*Question:* Other than continuous connection monitoring with [getStats()](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#getStats) and maybe the experimental [`navigator.connection` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation), how can the web-client monitor network connectivity?

**Pre-Call Test**

We recommend to customers to run a [pre-call test](https://tokbox.com/blog/pre-call-test-new-performance-diagnostic-tool/) and have implemented it on our site as well. However, results of that test often times *do not* reflect the in-session connectivity. Worse, a pre-call test may detect a low (no video) bandwidth while Skype works just fine.

*Question:* How can that be?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a member of the TokBox development team. I remember you reported an issue with the Python SDK, thanks for that!

**Web-Client: A/V Resources**

Most acquisition issues are detected by the JS SDK and if they aren't then we'd really like to hear about it! Please report reproduction steps or affected session IDs to TokBox support (referencing this StackOverflow question): https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Most acquisition errors appear as `OT_HARDWARE_UNAVAILABLE` or `OT_MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED` errors. Are you detecting and surfacing these errors to your users? There is also the special `OT_CHROME_MICROPHONE_ACQUISITION_ERROR` error which is due to a known issue with Chrome that has been mostly fixed since Chrome 63 (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4799).

**Web-Client: Network**

Unfortunately this is one of the more difficult issues to troubleshoot. Yes, `Subscriber#getStats()` is the best tool we have at our disposal and is a wrapper around the native `RTCPeerConnection#getStats()` function. Unfortunately we don't have much control over the values returned by the native function and if you think our SDK is returning incorrect values when compared with values from `RTCPeerConnection#getStats()` then please let us know!

It would be worthwhile confirming whether the issue is reproducible in all browsers or only a particular one. If you have detailed data regarding the inaccuracy of the native `RTCPeerConnection#getStats()` function then we could work together to report it to the browser vendor(s).

*Fortunately* we have just released the new [Publisher#getStats()](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#getStats) function which lets you get the publisher side of the stats. This should help you narrow down the cause of a connectivity issue to either a publisher or subscriber side. Please let us know if this helps with tracking down these issues.

**Pre-Call Test**

Again, these tests are based on `Subscriber#getStats()` which in turn are based on `RTCPeerConnection#getStats()`, the accuracy of which is out of our hands, but we'd love any reproduction steps to either fix a bug in our client SDK or report a bug to the browser vendors.

Just to confirm though, when you say you've implemented a pre-call test in your site, did you use the official JavaScript network test module? https://github.com/opentok/opentok-network-test-js This is actually what's used by the TokBox pre-call test.

Answer (score 0):

@Aiham, thanks for responding, I've been looking at the the new [Publisher#getStats()](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#getStats) you linked to (thank you!), so we too can give our users some way of visibly seeing the network conditions that might be affected the quality of their call (and who's causing it). However, it seems as though bytes / packets sent goes up sharply as the number of subscribers increases, even though we're in a [routed](https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/202997234-What-is-the-difference-between-a-Routed-vs-Relayed-Session-) session.

Am I wrong to expect the [Publisher#getStats()](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#getStats) statistics to stay fairly stable regardless of the number of subscribers then receiving that stream in a routed session? I expected the nature of a routed call to mean it's sent once to the OpenTok Media Servers, and the statistics would end there.